# Phonegap Cordova 3.6.3 inappbrowser does not exist

Tags: eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using Phonegap `Cordova 3.6.3` and run my project in eclipse i found an error

```
10-30 11:13:42.463: E/Web Console(2447): Uncaught Error: Module org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.inappbrowser does not exist. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1385
```

Comment: I guess you did not add the in app browser plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use core plugins like inapp browser, you need first to add the plugin.

I suggest you read the docs : http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

**Installation :**

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

(This is since version 3.x of cordova/phonegap. Before that all core plugins where included)